# Cannot run content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have written a code for writing google chrome extension but the problem is that i cannot execute the content script in the chrome console.
Here is my following code

For Manifest file:-

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "My new extension",
      "description": "It does stuff",
      "version": "1"
      "content_scripts": [
    {
       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "js": ["content.js"]
     }
   ]
 }
```

For my content script:-

```
     console.log("Hello world!");
```

When i deploy the extension, it is accepted properly. It should be printed at chrome console but when i refresh, nothing is printed.
Can please anyone help me where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some pages cannot be scripted, fr example the default new tab page, or an extension-controlled new tab page, or pages of an extension, or the built-in browser UI pages. Also see if you've changed filtering levels in devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to inject content scripts you need to add at least the following permission in manifest:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab"]
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: The OP's manifest already permits all URLs. The activeTab permission's use case is orthogonal to that.